# Simple two volt source circuit - Current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

THIS CIRCUIT:

[image]

A=5.6 kΩ , B=5.6 kΩ, and C=10 kΩ.

How the HECK do I find the currents through each resistor? Absolutely no clue.

**Note:** I understand Kirchhoff's Laws and Ohm's Law perfectly well - it's just this one circuit that gets me.

Comment: This is a strange circuit diagram, because there appears to be a short as there is no resistance between the two nodes where the voltage is defined and the 'COM' node.  Did you redraw the diagram or did this come from the source?

Comment: @tmwilson26 I thought the same - I figure it's a lab manual messup. How about this new circuit I've drawn?

Comment: For this circuit, you should just be able to use Ohm's law, $V=IR$.  You can determine $V$ around each resistor based on this diagram, where 'COM' is presumably $0 \text{ V}$.  So, write down what the voltage is on each side of each resistor, and note which way the current flows if signs matter.

Comment: @tmwilson26 So... C gets 12V, and B gets 5V? What does A get? 7V?

Comment: Yes, note that the current over $R_C$ and $R_B$ are flowing in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually much simpler than you think - Kirchoff not needed.

If you have a known voltage on the terminals of a resistor, you can compute the current directly from Ohm's law. This is the case for $R_A$ where you have a voltage of (12-5)V.

You need to know the nature of the COM terminal to calculate the other two. If COM == ground, then the voltage across $R_C$ is 12 V (with current flowing to the right) and the voltage across $R_B$ is 5 V (with current flowing to the left).

If COM is floating, then the two resistors are in series; this means their total resistance is $R_B+R_C$ and the voltage across them is once again (12-5) V.

Comment: *"Kirchoff not needed"* - To be sure, you applied KVL to find the voltage across $R_A$ etc.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - I don't think of "a resistor has a voltage across it - what is the current" as an application of KVL. But strictly speaking, I suppose there is a (not drawn) loop there.

Comment: The KVL equation clockwise 'round the loop is:  $V_{R_A} + 5V - 12V = 0$ or $V_{R_A} = (12 - 5)V$.  In other words, the equation you wrote for the voltage across $R_A$ *is* a KVL equation in fact and not just in some pedantic, strictly speaking, sense.

Comment: As I said - "not drawn". Which is why I didn't think of it as a loop, and didn't consider it to be that. But you are right. I didn't intend for you to think I was calling you pedantic - apologies if I came across that way.